# Javascript client lazy-loading models from ASP.NET MVC backend

Tags: c#, javascript, repository, lazy-loading

I'm developing a rich client web application which deals with a large volume of information. After a few stumbling blocks coming up with an application architecture, I've boiled down the following list of requirements:

- I need a javascript repository which can pull data from an ASP.NET MVC3 backend.
- I need to lazy-load or fetch-load specific properties of repository entities.

Is there a Javascript library that can do some or all of this - especially the lazy loading?

Comment: Although I think this question can't be answered objectively because there's a ton of things to consider **AND** whatever answer you accept will apply only for you, I don't think this question should be posted in a Q&A website. That being said, you might want to look [**this project**](https://github.com/MilkyWayJoe/hello-ember-router) I started, which is only for learning EmberJs on top of MVC4 Web API. It might be helpful for you. As for lazy loading, you might wanna look into [Ember-Data](https://github.com/emberjs/data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed some backbone application architectures and settled on eager loading most of the models upfront.